# AND and OR operator

Tags: c++, c

```
int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;
m=++i&&++j||++k;
```

according to me output should be -2 3 1 1...but why is it -2 3 0 1? 
Similarly ,

```
m=++i||++j&&++k;
gives -2 2 0 1?
```

can anybody explain?

Comment: It's a good question, it just happens to have an answer already.

Comment: I was going to read the entire question, but I'm lazy, so I stopped once I realized that reading the rest wouldn't change the result.